Getting Document Similarity Scores with SelfQueryRetriever - Langchain
I want to be able to get the similarity scores of the retrieved documents when using the SelfQueryRetriever as seen below.
I have made a selfquery retriever as follows:
retriever = SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
    llm = llm,
    vectorstore = vectorstore,
    document_contents = document_content_description,
    metadata_field_info = metadata_field_info,
    enable_limit=True, 
    search_type = "similarity_score_threshold",
    search_kwargs={"score_threshold": 0.80, "k": 5},
    verbose=True
)

The retriever is able to retrieve documents as expected, but I would like to somehow display the similarity score of the retrieved documents. Can this be done and how? As is the retriever returns Documents with page_content and metadata keys.

Reference: how to add scores
What you can do is sub-class SelfQueryRetriever and ensure score is returned along with the documents. This can be achieved by using the similarity_search_with_score method
from langchain.retrievers.self_query.base import SelfQueryRetriever
from typing import Any, Dict

from typing import Any, Dict


class CustomSelfQueryRetriever(SelfQueryRetriever):
    def _get_docs_with_query(
        self, query: str, search_kwargs: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> List[Document]:
        """Get docs, adding score information."""
        docs, scores = zip(
            *self.vectorstore.similarity_search_with_score(query, **search_kwargs)
        )
        for doc, score in zip(docs, scores):
            doc.metadata["score"] = score

        return docs

retriever = CustomSelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
    llm = llm,
    vectorstore = vectorstore,
    document_contents = document_content_description,
    metadata_field_info = metadata_field_info,
    enable_limit=True, 
    search_type = "similarity_score_threshold",
    search_kwargs={"score_threshold": 0.80, "k": 5},
    verbose=True
)


result = retriever.invoke("your query")

Now your Document metadata willcontain a key named score

Yes, The similarity score isn't returned in the Document object
So, You can use below code to get similarity scores,
# retrieves the top k documents and their similarity scores based on the query.
results_with_scores = vectorstore.similarity_search_with_score(query, k=5)
for doc, score in results_with_scores:
    print(f"Document: {doc.page_content}")
    print(f"Similarity Score: {score}")

results_with_scores is a list of tuples with below,

doc: Document with page_content and metadata.
score: The similarity score comparing the query and the document.

